# Alternative to LBA for recognising context-sensitive languages

Tags: automata-theory, grammars, space-bounded

I've always felt that there's no "canonical" automata for recognising context-sensitive languages. Much like there's DFA for regular, PDA for context-free and Turing machines for RE.

I'm aware of LBA, but that's a finite restriction of Turing machines. In my view, it doesn't really stand on its own.

I once read a paper which gave a very interesting alternative, but I can't find it anymore. A link to that paper would be great, but I'd appreciate something more substantive too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an alternative model:

Benedek Nagy: Left-most derivation and shadow-pushdown automata for context-sensitive languages, ICCOMP'06: Proceedings of the 10th WSEAS international conference on Computers, pp. 1015-1020.

Comment: Oh, wow. It's different from the paper I expected, but it's still very good. It's nice to know there are multiple alternatives.